# conditional formatting to highlight the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010 and would like to know if there's any way I can choose conditional formatting to highlight the cell from a table/list after a value has been entered.

For instance, when entering a value in the cell can a choice be prompted to request the category of the value and then highlight the cell keeping the value there?

E.g 1 FTE value is entered in a cell. The 1 FTE value can be either Annual Leave (Blue), Sick Leave (Yellow) or Long Service Leave (Pink). Is there a way to prompt the user to select the type of leave it is?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the screenshot below

[image]

When a value is entered in row 2, the corresponding cell in row 3 turns red until a value is entered into that cell. This is done with a conditional format using a rule, starting in B3 and applied to the cells at the right.

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(B2),ISBLANK(B3))
```

Note that there are no $ signs in the cell references because they need to be relative to the current cell.